# how to mimic debugger functionality of controlling a value at particular memory location

Tags: c, debugging, memory, gcc

I would like to mimic debugger functionality of controlling a value at a particular memory location,whenever the memory location is written with a value I would like to override with my value.
I have a dll which I have imported in simulink environment and I would like to control(overwrite) the value at particular memory location(variable in dll), something like modern debuggers allow.I am using gcc compiler.I do not want to attach gdb/eclipse to matlab session.I tried with exception handling(for gcc is it not so good) however I am able to put a data break point (memory write breakpoint using debug registers)at the address but not able to overwrite this value.The program just crashes/hangs if I try to clear the debug register in the handler and write my value to the location.

Please suggest solutions to solve the problem!!!